# Tabular inside itemize - bullet vertical align

Tags: tables, itemize

I am trying to align text inside an unordered list.

```latex
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
        when size = capacity $\Rightarrow$ resize $\Rightarrow$ &capacity increased \\ 
                                                                &a bigger array is allocated \\
                                                                &existing elements are copied to the new array
        \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
```

Here is the result:

[image: result]

However, the bullet is vertically centered. How can I make it stay at the top?

Comment: Try `begin{tabuler}[t]{rl}`

Comment: @Bernard that did the trick! Thank you! Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it, please? :)

Comment: Thank you, but I think it's not necessary –  there are already many comments recalling the tabular environments have an optional argument to specify the vertical alignment w.r.t. the surrounding text (default  is `c`),  as there is the same argument for  `aligned, gathered, …` .